# Failed to load a keras model to my raspberry pi3 b+

Tags: raspbian, python-3

I am trying to load a keras model to do classification task using my raspberry.
But after running this code:

```
import keras
from keras.models import load_model

model = load_model("mobilenet_v2_3(trained).h5")
```

before i will be able to do some prediction, i got this error;

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Instructions for updating:
Colocations handled automatically by placer.
Backend terminated(returncode: -11)
Fatal python error: Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Bad luck.  So you have a segFault.  Most likely your big data is too big.  Ref: Identify what's causing segmentation faults 
https://kb.iu.edu/d/aqsj

Comment: Do you suggest a kind of solution Please @tlfong01

Comment: Well, I am a small guy, don't know nothing about big data, not even scratching surface knowledge.  But now everybody is talking about AI, Neural Net and TensorFlow, etc.  I am losing face because I can't even tell what is the difference between Neural Net and TensorFlow.  So I am keen to dig deeper below the surface, memorize more weird names, so that my friends would respect more than I deserve.  My plan is first wiki, and pretend to give an answer.  Perhaps you can also pretend to give an answer, then I upvote you, and upvote me, building our reputation together, ... :)